# Show that $\mathrm{O}(q)$ is the union of a set of vector symmetries and the set of applications $\gamma_a$

Tags: finite-groups, quadratic-forms, symmetry, orthogonal-matrices

We fix $q$ the quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $q\left(x_1, x_2\right)=x_1 x_2$. Let

$$\mathrm{O}(q)=\left\{f \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \mid q(x)=q(f(x)) \text { pour tout } x \in \mathbb{R}^2\right\}$$

Show that $\mathrm{O}(q)$ is the union of a set of vector symmetries and the set of applications $\gamma_a$ defined by $\gamma_a\left(e_1\right)=a e_1$ and $\gamma_a\left(e_2\right)=a^{-1} e_2$ (for $a \in \mathbb{R}^*$ ).

I know that the matrix of $q$ in the canonical basis is
$$M_q = \left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
and the relation $q(x) = q(f(x))$ gives that if $P$ is the matrix of $f \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}) $ then
$$ M_q = P^t M_q P. 
$$
What do I have to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ P= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix} $ be an element of $O(q)$,then $\forall x_{1},x_{2}\in \mathbb{R},acx_{1}+(ad+bc)x_{1}x_{2}+bd x_{2} =x_{1}x_{2}$ so,we must have $ac=bd=0$ and $ad+bc=1$,if $a=0$, then $c\neq 0 ,b\neq 0$, so $d=0$ and $bc=1$, in particular, $P$ must be of the form: $ P_{b}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b \\
b^{-1} & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} $
if $a\neq 0$, then necesarly $c=b=0,ad=1$,So $P$ must be of the form: $ P= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & a^{-1} \\
\end{pmatrix} $
which correspond to $\gamma_{\alpha}$,finally remark that $P_{b}=R\circ\gamma_{b^{-1}}$ where $R$ is a reflection along the line having equation $x_{2}=x_{1}$